# PropType error in React form input type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, prop, react-proptypes

I am building a form with react.js and having an issue I cannot seem to resolve. Am using the npm module `prop-types` for my props within the form and trying to set an `inputType` for a single input. I keep getting the following error:

[image]

My code for this is:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const SingleInput = (props) => (
    <div className="form-group">
        <label className="form-label">{props.title}</label>
        <input
            className="form-input"
            name={props.name}
            type={props.inputType}
            value={props.content}
            onChange={props.controlFunc}
            placeholder={props.placeholder} />
    </div>
);



SingleInput.propTypes = {
    inputType: React.PropTypes.oneOfType(['text', 'number']).isRequired,
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    controlFunc: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    content: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
        React.PropTypes.string,
        React.PropTypes.number,
    ]).isRequired,
    placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
};

export default SingleInput;
```

I have switched between using `oneOf` and then `oneOfType`, but get the same results either way. Is there something further I should do?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you use React v16 ? You can read in their release note that they removed `PropTypes` from their `react` package.

> The deprecations introduced in 15.x have been removed from the core
>   package. React.createClass is now available as create-react-class,
>   React.PropTypes as prop-types, React.DOM as react-dom-factories,
>   react-addons-test-utils as react-dom/test-utils, and shallow renderer
>   as react-test-renderer/shallow

You should directly use the `prop-types` library:

```
SingleInput.propTypes = {
    inputType: PropTypes.oneOfType(['text', 'number']).isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    controlFunc: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    content: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.number,
    ]).isRequired,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Comment: Yeah, my problem was I added the `prop-types` library, but still had `React.PropTypes` rather than just `PropTypes`.

Comment: `PropTypes.oneOfType` should be `PropTypes.oneOf` if using an array of string literals as `PropTypes.oneOfType` expects an array of more PropTypes.

Answer (score 2):

`oneOfType` means that you expect the variable to be one of a specific prop-type, while `oneOf` can be any self choosen value.
Here an example how both would look like.

```
Game.propTypes = {      
  gameStatus: PropTypes.oneOf(['new_game', 'playing', 'finished']).isRequired,
  roundsToPlay: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]).isRequired,
}
```

I came here because i had a problem with a `<input type="number" />` element. I wanted to have the value as props, but every time the user would remove default value to type in a new one i would get a warning from prop-types. As the value is now an empty string instead of any given number. The solution is to set the prop-type with `oneOfTypes` to accept string and number.

I hope i could help someone with this additional information with the same problem on number inputs.